# How can I reborrow a mutable reference without passing it to a function?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have found a case where manually inlining a function changes the way the borrow-checker treats it, such that it no longer compiles. Presumably it is relying on the information in the function signature. How can I provide this information in the inlined version?

### How I think it's working

Let `'a` and `'b` be lifetimes with `'a` shorter than `'b` (which can be written `'b: 'a`).

Suppose I have a `p: &'b mut f32`. I can borrow `p` briefly (with `&mut p`) to obtain `q: &'a mut &'b mut f32`.

1. Have I correctly understood that `&'a mut &'b mut f32` is equivalent to `&'a mut &'a mut f32` because `'b: 'a`?

I can then dereference `q` (with `*q`) to obtain `r: &'a mut f32`. I can write to the `f32` via `r` (with `*r = something`), and I can later (outside lifetime `'a`) read back the value via `p` (with `*p`).

### With a function call

Here is some working code that I think uses the above sequence:

```
fn reborrow<'a, 'b: 'a>(q: &'a mut &'b mut f32) -> &'a mut f32 {
    *q
}

fn main() {
    let mut x: f32 = 3.142;
    let mut p = &mut x;
    {
        let q = &mut p;
        let r = reborrow(q);
        *r = 2.718;
    }
    assert_eq!(*p, 2.718);
}
```

(Replacing `*q` with `q` in the body of `reborrow()` also works, because Rust inserts the necessary dereference if it is missing).

### Manually inlined

If I manually inline the `reborrow()` call, it no longer compiles:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: f32 = 3.142;
    let mut p = &mut x;
    {
        let q = &mut p;
        let r = *q; <-- ERROR REPORTED HERE.
        *r = 2.718;
    }
    assert_eq!(*p, 2.718);
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
```

2. Who took away my toys? What is the type inference thinking/missing?
3. Can I annotate the `let` binding somehow to make the compiler infer the same types as in the previous version?

### Some other attempts

Here's another version that works, but which doesn't define the name `r`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: f32 = 3.142;
    let mut p = &mut x;
    {
        let q = &mut p;
        **q = 2.718;
    }
    assert_eq!(*p, 2.718);
}
```

Here's a work-around that defines the name `r` and works, but does not use the same sequence of borrows and dereferences:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: f32 = 3.142;
    let mut p = &mut x;
    {
        let q = &mut p;
        let r = &mut **q;
        *r = 2.718;
    }
    assert_eq!(*p, 2.718);
}
```

I made a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e5c5658e05cff967c1e4b1df0c3d50ce) combining all four versions.

Comment: FWIW, I had a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43036307/155423) based on your `reborrow` method.

Comment: This might help a little: https://bluss.github.io/rust/fun/2015/10/11/stuff-the-identity-function-does/

Comment: @BurntSushi5 I had similar thoughts, but the `{}` trick *doesn't* work here, which seems to indicate it's different somehow.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 Entertaining, though. :-)

Answer (score 14):

The obvious solution works, as one could expect:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: f32 = 3.142;
    let mut p = &mut x;
    {
        let r: &mut f32 = p;
        *r = 2.718;
    }
    assert_eq!(*p, 2.718);
}
```

It seems relatively intuitive and is what I would expect a newcomer to end up with.

---

If you start thinking about it, however, it will not make sense. As described, it looks like:

- `let r: &mut f32 = p;` moves *out* of `p`
- and yet we use `p` later in `assert_eq!(*p, 2.718);`

A reasonable explanation would be that `p` is `Copy`, however it's not<sup>1</sup>!

The answer is that, implicitly, Rust is performing a *re-borrowing* behind the scenes. That is, the explicit code is:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: f32 = 3.142;
    let mut p = &mut x;
    {
        let r: &mut f32 = &mut *p;
        *r = 2.718;
    }
    assert_eq!(*p, 2.718);
}
```

We can check this by attempting to read `p` after re-borrowing it, and check the compiler error:

> ```
> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `p` as immutable because `*p` is also borrowed as mutable
>  --> <anon>:6:24
>   |
> 5 |         let r: &mut f32 = p;
>   |                           - mutable borrow occurs here
> 6 |         println!("{}", p);
>   |                        ^ immutable borrow occurs here
> 7 |         *r = 2.718;
> 8 |     }
>   |     - mutable borrow ends here
>
> error: aborting due to previous error
> ```

Which confirms that `p` is indeed only borrowed mutably, and not moved, cloned or copied.

<sup>1</sup> *A mutable reference cannot be `Copy` or even `Clone` as it would violate the Aliasing XOR Mutability principle which underpins Rust safety.*

Comment: Well, I suppose this confirms what I wrote in the question at least. Do you have a model of how the type inference is working/breaking in this case?

Comment: @apt1002: Sorry, no. I understand what happens, but I don't know for sure. It could be as simple as re-borrow if the variable is used down the line, move otherwise, but there may be edge cases I am failing to account for.

Answer (score 3):

I can't possibly begin to explain this, but you can do a similar trick as the implicit dereference and say that `r` is `&mut f32`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x: f32 = 3.142;
    let mut p = &mut x;
    {
        let q = &mut p;
        let r: &mut f32 = q;
        *r = 2.718;
    }
    assert_eq!(*p, 2.718);
}
```

Comment: Gosh, even `let r: &mut f32 = *q;` works. Very odd. I'm really looking forward to an explanation!