# Why can't I mutably borrow a primitive from an enum?

Tags: enums, rust, borrow-checker

I would like to be able to obtain references (both immutable and mutable) to the `usize` wrapped in `Bar` in the `Foo` enum:

```
use Foo::*;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub enum Foo {
    Bar(usize)
}

impl Foo {
    /* this works */
    fn get_bar_ref(&self) -> &usize {
        match *self {
            Bar(ref n) => &n
        }
    }

    /* this doesn't */
    fn get_bar_ref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut usize {
        match *self {
            Bar(ref mut n) => &mut n
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't obtain the mutable reference because:

> `n` does not live long enough

I was able to provide both variants of similar functions accessing other contents of `Foo` that are `Box`ed - why does the mutable borrow (and why only it) fail with an unboxed primitive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These examples show the sample problem:

```
fn implicit_reborrow<T>(x: &mut T) -> &mut T {
    x
}

fn explicit_reborrow<T>(x: &mut T) -> &mut T {
    &mut *x
}

fn implicit_reborrow_bad<T>(x: &mut T) -> &mut T {
    &mut x
}

fn explicit_reborrow_bad<T>(x: &mut T) -> &mut T {
    &mut **&mut x
}
```

The `explicit_` versions show what the compiler deduces through [deref coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html).
The `_bad` versions both error in the exact same way, while the other two compile.

This is either a bug, or a limitation in how lifetimes are currently implemented in the compiler. The invariance of `&mut T` over `T` *might* have something to do with it, because it results in `&mut &'a mut T` being invariant over `'a` and thus *more restrictive* during inference than the shared reference (`&&'a T`) case, even though *in this situation* the strictness is unnecessary.

Answer (score 8):

You need to replace `Bar(ref mut n) => &mut n` with `Bar(ref mut n) => n`.

When you use `ref mut n` in `Bar(ref mut n)`, it creates a mutable
reference to the data in `Bar`, so the type of `n` is `&mut usize`.
Then you try to return `&mut n` of `&mut &mut u32` type.

> **This part is most likely incorrect.**
>
> Now [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html) kicks in
>   and converts `&mut n` into `&mut *n`, creating a temporary value `*n`
>   of type `usize`, which doesn't live long enough.

Comment: That's still odd. Why isn't the behaviour the same for `get_bar_ref`?

Comment: According to the nomicon link you gave, `&T` coerces to `*const T` and `&mut T` to `*mut T`. It is still unclear to me why mutability affects the life span of the variable.

Comment: Interesting. According to documentation `&Bar(ref n) => &n` should expand to `&Bar(ref n) => &*(n.deref())`, but it doesn't compile. I suppose there's some compiler magic involved.

Comment: It is probably have something to do with [reborrowing of mutable references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036156/how-can-i-reborrow-a-mutable-reference-without-passing-it-to-a-function)

Comment: I do not believe this has anything to do with deref coercions.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I thought `n` was still not a reference and `ref` only avoided having it moved in the `match` branch; my `Box`ed cases also seemed to confirm this - `Foo(ref boxed) => &*boxed` gives the reference to the contents of the `Box`, I don't need an additional deref (`&**boxed`). I'll give the question a bit more time, maybe someone can explain the reason why it depends on mutability; otherwise, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Deref coercions *cannot possibly* create temporaries. What's happening has be a difference between `&mut **&mut n` (which is what deref coercions will effectively result in on that example) and `&mut *n` (which *does* work). It's unlikely to be required for soundness (since both versions do the *exact same* operation), but due to invariance under mutable references the lifetimes likely get "tightened" more than they should be. Can't find it now but it's possible this issue has been reported before.

Comment: @ljedrz If you have `Foo(ref boxed)`, then `*boxed: Box<T>` and `**boxed: T`, so `&**boxed: &T`. *However*, `boxed: &Box<T>` will happily coerce to `&T` (through deref coercions). `&*boxed: &Box<T>` is equivalent to simply using `boxed`.