# A bit problem about Rust's function parameter and ownership

Tags: rust, ownership

here's my problem:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");
    let s1 = &mut s;
    let s2 = s1;

    *s2 = String::from("world1");
    *s1 = String::from("world2");

    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

it will result in a compile error because s1 has type **`&mut String`** which doesn't implement the **`Copy`** trait.

But if I change the code as below:

```
fn c(s: &mut String) -> &mut String {
    s
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");
    let s1 = &mut s;
    let s2 = c(s1);

    *s2 = String::from("world1");
    *s1 = String::from("world2");

    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

it will compile without any error message.

I know when a reference passed to a function, it means the reference **`borrows`** the value insteading of owning it.

But in the situation above, it seems like when s1 was passed to **`fn c`** and returned immediatelly, s2 **`borrowed`** s1 so s1 couldn't be derefed until s2 was out of it's lifetime scope.

So what happened when s1 was passed into the **`fn c`**?

Comment: Instead of doing `let s2 =c(s1);`, you could do `let s2 = &mut *s1;` : A reference isn't `Copy` but you can take a new reference as is done in the function. Note that this isn't an answer: I'm not clear enough regarding the rules leading to the dereference in `c`.

Comment: It *looks like* you have two mutable references to the same string, but if you add `println!("{:?}", s2);` after `*s1 = String::from("world2");` you'll get `cannot assign to *s1 because it is borrowed`. So I **guess** that this is somehow caused by NLL. Pretty interesting question though.

Comment: PS: The same happens if you reborrow s1 without `fn c`: `let s2 = &mut *s1;` So I guess, in the `fn c()` case, rustc is performing a reborrow under the cover, while in `s2 = s1` case it's just doing a `move`. Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036156/how-can-i-reborrow-a-mutable-reference-without-passing-it-to-a-function

Comment: This is definitely a stumbling block for many people new to Rust. Fortunately I think Sven's answer to the duplicate is a really good explanation of why this is the case.

Comment: From that answer, another way of making the function compile is to give `s2` a reference type explicitly: `let s2: &mut _ = s1;` will work fine because the compiler will infer a reborrow any time the destination is known to be a mutable reference.

Comment: It's not surprising that this is a stumbling block for Rust learners, since the behaviour is both both counter-intuitive and undocumented. In my opionion, it was a mistake to introduce implicit reborrows for mutable references.

Answer (score 1):

From @Denys Séguret's hint, I guess when s1 was passed to **`fn C`**, Rust core compiled the parameter **`s1`** to something like **`&mut *s1`**, so there was an immutable borrow of s1.

That's why if we put

```
*s2 = String::from("world1");
```

behind

```
*s1 = String::from("world2");
```

Rust would tell us:

```
assignment to borrowed `*s1`
```

And when s2 goes out of it's lifetime scope, there is no borrow of s1 anymore, so s1 can be derefed again.

But I'm not quite sure whether it's a right explanation.

Comment: It seems like a special case because if you use an identity function instead of `c` then it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by an identity function?

Comment: nevermind......